# ui-select not rendering select option in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, autocomplete

I'm using the ui-select from [HERE](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) and its working well in all the browsers, But in IE 8 I'm not able to see the option exactly same issue as faced in one of the open issue on the page from [HERE](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/90), you may use the [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview) as reference.

I tried but in vain did not work out. Can someone help me out in solving this issue or a hint how should I approach to this problem.

```
 <ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
  <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
</ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the github issue, you need to have these lines loaded before IE8 knows what to do with those custom elements

```
document.createElement('ui-select');
document.createElement('ui-select-match');
document.createElement('ui-select-choices');
```

Comment: Yeah i have did that but still not getting the view rendered